# It seems that Spark RDD's cache doesn't work, since there is no RDD on Spark web UI

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am going to test Spark's RDD cache by running PythonPageRank on CentOS 7:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster /usr/spark/examples/src/main/python/pagerank.py input/testpr.txt 10
```

As you can see, I am doing the PageRank, therefore **testpr.txt** and **10** are the parameters.
The file *pagerank.py* contains the following code:

```py
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("PythonPageRank")\
        .getOrCreate()

    lines = spark.read.text(sys.argv[1]).rdd.map(lambda r: r[0])

    links = lines.map(lambda urls: parseNeighbors(urls)).distinct().groupByKey().cache()

    ranks = links.map(lambda url_neighbors: (url_neighbors[0], 1.0))

    for iteration in range(int(sys.argv[2])):
        contribs = links.join(ranks).flatMap(
            lambda url_urls_rank: computeContribs(url_urls_rank[1][0], url_urls_rank[1][1]))
        ranks = contribs.reduceByKey(add).mapValues(lambda rank: rank * 0.85 + 0.15)

    for (link, rank) in ranks.collect():
        print("%s has rank: %s." % (link, rank))

    spark.stop()
```

As you can see,`links = lines.map(lambda urls: parseNeighbors(urls)).distinct().groupByKey().cache()` contains **cache**. However, when I look at the Spark UI's Storage page, I can't find anything about **cache**.

Here is the **PageRank application**, it works well.
[image: The PageRank Application]

Here is the **Job page** of the application, the action `collect()` generates a job:
[image: The Job page]

Here is the **Stage page** of the application, it shows that there contains many iterations in PageRank.
[image: The Stage page]

Here is the **Storage page** of the application, which should contain cached RDDs. However, it contains nothing, seeming that the `cache()` doesn't work.
[image: The Storage page]

Why can't I see any cached RDDs on the **Storage page**? Why doesn't the `cache()` in *pagerank.py* work? Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `spark.eventLog.logBlockUpdates.enabled  true` into `spark-defaults.conf`, which won't make the Spark History Server's Storage tab be blank.